# How to use $filter(aggregation) to select some fields of array only if condition true?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here I'll show you what exactly I want. Suppose I have the below two document for XYZ model.

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "email" : "one@one.com",
        "mobileNumber" : "910123456989",
        "verificationStatus" : true,
        "activities" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "a1",
                "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139bae"),
                "type" : 0,
                "level" : null,
                "verificationStatus" : true
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "a2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139bad"),
                "type" : 0,
                "level" : null,
                "verificationStatus" : false
            } 
        ],
        "address" : {
            "line1" : "asd",
            "line2" : "asd",
            "city" : "sd",
            "state" : "sd",
            "country" : "asd",
            "landmark" : "sdsa",
            "pincode" : "560090"
        },
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "email" : "one@one.com",
        "mobileNumber" : "919876543210",
        "verificationStatus" : true,
        "activities" : [ 
            {
                "name" : "b1",
                "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139bae"),
                "level" : null,
                "type" : 0,
                "verificationStatus" : true
            }, 
            {
                "name" : "b2",
                "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139bad"),
                "level" : null,
                "type" : 0,
                "verificationStatus" : false
            }
        ],
        "address" : {
            "line1" : "asd",
            "line2" : "asd",
            "city" : "sd",
            "state" : "sd",
            "country" : "asd",
            "landmark" : "sdsa",
            "pincode" : "560090"
        },
        "__v" : 0
    }
]
```

Now I want only the `name`, `mobileNumber` and `activities.name` from the document where verificationStatus is true and I don't want all the activities I want activities.name only if `activities.varificationStatus` is `true`.

I can get the list of all document where `varificationStatus` is true and `activities.varificationStatus` is true but I'm not able to select only required fields (`activities.name`) from `activities`.

My current code is:

```
XYZ.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { verificationStatus: true } },
        {
            $project: {
                name: 1,
                coverImage: 1,
                location: 1,
                address: 1,
                dist: 1,
                activities: {
                    $filter: {
                        input: "$activities",
                        as: "activity",
                        cond: {
                            $eq: ["$$activity.verificationStatus", true]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }], function (err, list) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(list);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to "alter" the array elements returned, as [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) only "selects" the array elements that "match":

```
XYZ.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { verificationStatus: true } },
        {
            $project: {
                name: 1,
                mobileNumber: 1,
                activities: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $filter: {
                          input: "$activities",
                          as: "activity",
                          cond: "$$activity.verificationStatus"
                      }
                    },
                    "as": "a",
                    "in": "$$a.name"
                  }
                }
            }
        }], function (err, list) {
        ...
```

Would return:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "910123456989",
        "activities" : ["a1"]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "919876543210",
        "activities" : ["b1"]
}
```

Note also that the `"cond"` in [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) can be shortened since it's already a `boolean` value.

If you wanted the "object" with the property of `"name"` only, then return just that assigned key:

```
XYZ.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { verificationStatus: true } },
        {
            $project: {
                name: 1,
                mobileNumber: 1,
                activities: {
                  $map: {
                    input: {
                      $filter: {
                          input: "$activities",
                          as: "activity",
                          cond: "$$activity.verificationStatus"
                      }
                    },
                    "as": "a",
                    "in": {
                      "name": "$$a.name"
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }], function (err, list) {
        ...
```

Returns as:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "910123456989",
        "activities" : [{ "name": "a1" }]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "919876543210",
        "activities" : [{ "name": "b1" }]
}
```

If you knew for certain that you were matching "one" element in the array, then [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) with [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) could be used instead if you have MongoDB 3.4

```
{ "$project": {
  "name": 1,
  "mobileNumber": 1,
  "activities": {
    "$arrayElemAt": [
      "$activities.name",
      { "$indexOfArray": [ "$activities.verificationStatus", true ] }
    ]
  }
}}
```

Which would come out a little differently since it's a singular value and not an array:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "910123456989",
        "activities" : "a1"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59ef8786e8c7d60552139ba9"),
        "name" : "s1",
        "mobileNumber" : "919876543210",
        "activities" : "b1"
}
```